# Broken Favourite Tags Link

Tags: bug, hyperlinks, tag-watching

When I am on my preferences site: https://stackoverflow.com/users/preferences/1320237

And I click on [advanced tag subscriptions »](https://stackexchange.com/filters)

I get to this error page: https://stackexchange.com/error?aspxerrorpath=/filters/40147/favorite-tags

I frequently use this page to see questions with my tag-subscriptions.

How can I make my Tag-Subscriptions showable again? Is this the right place to ask this questions?

Here is another question when only comments were broken: [I am notified about old comments instead of new ones](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228500/i-am-notified-about-old-comments-instead-of-new-ones)

Comment: This is broken for Filtered Questions for me too, e.g. http://stackexchange.com/error?aspxerrorpath=/filters/127207/javascript. It was last working for me about 12 hours ago.

Comment: This seems to be resolved for me now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By doing nothing, this was resolved automatially.